# iPhone CoreLocation: Give user the option to re-enable location usage for an app

Tags: iphone, core-location

If a user declines permission for an app to use the user's location data, is there a way for the user to re-enable it later?  Or for me to programatically give the user the option from within the app?

Comment: I did find this, which partially answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631733/iphone-core-location-keeps-asking-for-permission .  Now I'm left with this:  is it possible to force the location prompt programatically once location usage has been denied by the user?

Answer (score 0):

I commented on that here:
[What are the rules behind "X would like to use your current location" on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287425/what-are-the-rules-behind-x-would-like-to-use-your-current-location-on-the-ipho/2291661#2291661)

You have to do this manually via the settings screen (and it's for all apps).